# Use Google SearchConsoleR Data in Shiny Application

Tags: r, google-search-console

I have created an API Key, OAuth 2.0 Client IDs json file, and a service accounts email. How can I automatically connect without opening up the browser for authentication to the google search console with the searchConsoleR package?

For `googleAnalyticsR` I did this

```
googleAuthR::gar_set_client(json = here::here("credentials/client_id.json"))
googleAnalyticsR::ga_auth(email = "email",
                          json_file = here::here("credentials/file.json"))
```

But I am unable to connect to the search console. Is there any good documentation how I can connect to google search console in an automatic way without authentication in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters")
gar_auth_service(json_file = "/service-account-key.json")
```